# R variable types changes after transposing data frame

Tags: r, data-structures, transpose, variable-types

I've always been confused by the variable types in R. Now I encountered a problem after transposing a data frame.

For example, I'm using `table()` to get a count of each factor in a certain vector:

```
data(iris)

count <- as.data.frame(table(iris$Species))
typeof(count$Var1)
# [1] "integer"

typeof(count$Freq)
# [1] "integer"
```

My 1st question would be, why is `count$Var1` "integer"? Can strings be "integer" too? But this does not matter because I can change the type by `count$Var1 <- as.character(count$Var1)`, then `typeof(count$Var1)` becomes "character".

Now I transpose this data frame by `transposed_count <- as.data.frame(t(count))`. But I get confused because:

```
typeof(transposed_count[1,])
[1] "list"

typeof(transposed_count[2,])
[1] "list"

transposed_count[2,]
     V1 V2 V3
Freq 50 50 50
```

For consequent use, I need `transposed_count[2,]` to be a numeric vector like:

```
transposed_count[2,]
[1] 50 50 50
```

How can I do that? And why did them become "list" after `t()`? Sorry if it's a stupid question. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My 1st question would be, why is `count$Var1` "integer"?

Because factors are have integer storage type

```
> is.factor(count$Var1)
[1] TRUE
```

and the "strings" in the iris `data.frame`, as is typical in R, are stored as factors.

> And why did them become "list" after `t()`?

When you transpose you get a matrix, and matrices must have the same storage class for each entry. What you'll actually get first is a matrix of characters, as the integer values will be coerced. Then, when you subsequently change to a `data.frame`, those characters will by default be coerced to (new) factors.

```
> t(count)
     [,1]     [,2]         [,3]       
Var1 "setosa" "versicolor" "virginica"
Freq "50"     "50"         "50" 

> transposed_count <- as.data.frame(t(count))

> transposed_count[2,1]
Freq 
  50 
Levels: 50 setosa
> as.numeric(transposed_count[2,1])
[1] 1
```

So what was a count of 50 now is a factor with a numeric value of 1! Not what you want.

As to why `typeof(transposed_count[1,])` is a list? As a horizontal slice of a data.frame it is actually a data.frame.

```
> is.data.frame(transposed_count[2,])
[1] TRUE
```

And data.frames are just lists with class information.

> But how can I get a "transposed" data frame then?

It sounds like you may want

```
> library(reshape2)
> dcast(melt(count), variable~Var1)
Using Var1 as id variables
  variable setosa versicolor virginica
1     Freq     50         50        50
```

> after I read all samples in, I'm gonna rbind all data frame

You'll have to ensure the columns line up appropriately. Depending on the analysis to come it may be more natural to `rbind` as is with another column indicating the source.

```
> count2 <- count
> count$source = "file1"
> count2$source = "file2"
> (mcount <- rbind(count,count2))
        Var1 Freq source
1     setosa   50  file1
2 versicolor   50  file1
3  virginica   50  file1
4     setosa   50  file2
5 versicolor   50  file2
6  virginica   50  file2
```

Now you don't have to worry about alignment if you do want to reshape later

```
> dcast(melt(mcount), ...~Var1)
Using Var1, source as id variables
  source variable setosa versicolor virginica
1  file1     Freq     50         50        50
2  file2     Freq     50         50        50
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! It became clearer to me. But how can I get a "transposed" data frame then?

Comment: I'm reading in a bunch of files, each file as each sample. Finally I need a data frame where the rows are samples, columns are the count of every element in each file/sample. So after I read all samples in, I'm gonna rbind all data frame. This is why I need it to be transposed. I'm going to put the "Var1" as colnames for the final data frame.

Comment: As @Roman Luštrik inferred, you are probably looking for something like `dcast(melt(count), ...~Var1)` from the `reshape2` library. However, depending on your analysis to come, the more natural shape may be to `rbind` the data in its original format, adding another column with a file/sample indicator. This would give you a "stacked" format.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I know there's a difference. When I searched for transposing a data frame, t() is the only answer I got. But acutally I shouldn't be using it for my purpose.

Answer (score 3):

`typeof` will tell you how R stores the data internally. For factors, this is integer. And `Var1` is a factor, see?

```
> class(count$Var1)
[1] "factor"
```

`transposed_counts` make no sense in this case. By transposing you destroy the data.frame logic. Transposing usually makes sense for matrices. If you want to "reflow" a data.frame, you could use something like `reshape` or any of its relatives.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you make the species names in Var1 into row names before transposing you avoid the issues with transpose converting everything to the same data type.

```
data(iris)
count <- as.data.frame(table(iris$Species))
row.names(count) <- count$Var1
count$Var1 <- NULL
transposed_count <- as.data.frame(t(count))
as.numeric(transposed_count[1,])
# [1] 50 50 50
```